# RAILS ERB. How to add 'class' to a form.select do loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add the class "browser-default" because materializecss is broken with new javascript updates that chrome released. I can't figure it out.

````
<%= f.label :physician_id, "Referring Physician Name", :class => "black-text" %><br>
  <%= f.select(:physician_id) do %> ```<=== ADD CLASS TO THIS
    <% @facility.order(facilityname: :asc).each do |facility| -%>
      <% facility.physician.order(lastname: :asc).each do |physician| -%>
         <%= content_tag(:option, physician.lastname + ", " + physician.firstname + " " + physician.title + " ["+physician.user.facilityname + "]", value: physician.id) %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is defined as:

```
select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

So, you have an object (`:physician_id`) and then nothing else - a block. You need two others arguments for passing the `options` argument, which is when you can declare the class the element will take.

For that:

```
<%= f.select(:physician_id, {}, {}, { class: 'any-class' }) do %>
```

Would work.

---

Additional

- Use `{ key: :value }` for creating hashes when possible (instead { :key => :value }).
- `-%>` isn't needed. Just `%>` works.
- The default order is ascending for `order` when not specified (`order(:facilityname)`).
- Use interpolation rather than concatenation.

So:

```
<%= f.label :physician_id, 'Referring Physician Name', class: 'black-text' %><br>
  <%= f.select(:physician_id) do %>
    <% @facility.order(:facilityname).each do |facility| %>
      <% facility.physician.order(:lastname).each do |physician| %>
         <%= content_tag(:option, "#{physician.lastname}, #{physician.firstname} #{physician.title} [#{physician.user.facilityname}]", value: physician.id) %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```